# Preventing iCloud from syncing internet accounts in OS X Mavericks

Tags: icloud, email

I have an email account that I wish to add to only one computer.

Unfortunately when I create the account, iCloud automatically syncs it with my other machines.

Any way to prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud syncs Internet Accounts through the Keychain. You can disable Internet Accounts syncing by disabling the Keychain service in System Preferences → iCloud.

Comment: This will disable all of keychain syncing, whereas the original question was related to just email accounts