# Setup Exchange account on Mail.app on only one mac

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange

I want to configure an exchange account on a Macbook. But Apple sets it up as an "Internet account" and sets that up on every mac associated with that apple id.

Is it possible to configure it only on the one mac?

I want to access Mail and Calendar on this one mac. I want nothing to go back to iCloud and sync on my other macs.

Comment: Could you explain what parts of exchange you wish to sync? Mail, notes, calendar, other?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer on a different question:
[Preventing iCloud from syncing internet accounts in OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/preventing-icloud-from-syncing-internet-accounts-in-os-x-mavericks)

To summarize, you disable Keychain access on your mac, and then add the exchange account.